# android finish current activity causes app close

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am executing maswebview class and I would like to finish only this activity. I tried `maswebview.this.finish()` but when executed, app is been closed. Then if I set a new view for the tab content, it is loaded properly and webviewmas dissapears but just for a while, then appears again fitting fullscreen. How to finish maswebview completely? ThanK you

```
public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                /*
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                Intent intentmas = new Intent (maswebview.this, mas.class);
                intentmas.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); 
                intentmas.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
                intentmas.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                intentmas.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                View vista = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("maswb", intentmas).getDecorView();
                setContentView(vista);  */

                maswebview.this.finish();
```

Comment: add the full stack trace of your exception

Comment: you must add here more relevant code, this is not enough to say something.

Comment: yes, sorry, please see edits. There is no exception on logcat, app is just closed without errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have any other activities of your app in the stack by the time you call finish()? If you don't, you'll want to start the desired activity instead of finishing the current one.

But actually it seems to me that you're trying to accomplish something that can be done simpler. Can you provide more info on the task at hand and your app structure you're trying to go about it with?

From what you said, it seems like you have tabbed UI and you're trying to show a webview in one of the tabs, then hide it.

First, I don't see why you want the webview in a separate activity. Seems to me you could just have it in layout of one of the tabs and just call setVisibility(GONE) to hide it.

Second - **and this is important** - looks like you're trying to implement tabs the *old* way - TabWidget, TabHost, etc. Since Honeycomb has been released, there's much more convenient way to implement tabbed UI - [Action Bar Tabs and Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) - that approach is much more convenient and will render your webview problems obsolete: there's a thing called [WebViewFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewFragment.html) which is basically a WebView but smarter - it will handle its own lifecycle with minimum effort required from you (i.e. pause when removed, resume when added). It will take some effort to study up on Fragments, but it's well worth it. You can get Fragments API for pre-Honeycomb android sdks as a static library - it's called android-support-v4 and you can download it in Android SDK Manager.

Comment: WebViewFragment was a starting point to reach it! I appreciate so much your help

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling "maswebview.this.finish();" before the new Activity is started?

Also if you want to just start this new activity without having the old activity in existence then you can add android:nohistory="true" to your manifest.xml. This will cause the current activity to be the only activity in the queue.
See [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist)

You need to provide a little more information for us to better understand what exactly is going on.

I hope this helps.

Comment: both methods doesn't work completely but good link as starting point... +1

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
        if(childView != null && parentLayout.getChildCount()==2){
            childView.stopLoading();
            parentLayout.removeViewAt(parentLayout.getChildCount()-1);
            if(webView.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{          
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a parent activity which is launching this one? If yes make sure you don't call finish() after launching maswebview, that way the parent activity will remain in the stack. Once maswebview would exit, onResume would be called for your parent activity.